# prtdiag PS output explanation

Tags: unix, solaris, sun

Hi I have a SUN machine V240 which is reporting power supply failed.

In the prtdiag voltage sensors you can see FF_UV and P_PWR for PS1 is reporting failed.

What does these sensor refer to? other that power supply PS1 what else need to be replace?

```
Voltage sensors:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Location   Sensor        Voltage  Lo     LoWarn  HiWarn   Hi    Status
------------------------------------------------------------------------
MB         V_VTT          1.25V       -     1.17V   1.43V     -   okay
MB         V_GBE_+2V5     2.51V       -     2.25V   2.75V     -   okay
MB         V_GBE_CORE     1.20V       -     1.08V   1.32V     -   okay
MB         V_VCCTM        2.54V       -     2.25V   2.75V     -   okay
MB         V_+2V5         2.49V       -     2.34V   2.86V     -   okay
MB         V_+1V5         1.51V       -     1.35V   1.65V     -   okay
MB/BAT     V_BAT          2.97V       -     2.70V     -       -   okay
MB/P0      V_CORE         1.48V       -     1.26V   1.54V     -   okay
MB/P1      V_CORE         1.48V       -     1.26V   1.54V     -   okay
PS0        FF_UV            -         -       -       -       -   okay
PS0        FF_OV            -         -       -       -       -   okay
PS0        P_PWR            -         -       -       -       -   okay
**PS1        FF_UV            -         -       -       -       -   failed**
PS1        FF_OV            -         -       -       -       -   okay
**PS1        P_PWR            -         -       -       -       -   failed**
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last month on a V245. 
I am guessing that FF_OV and UV are overvoltage and undervoltage sensors, but I really didn't find anything on this.
The PS1 will have to be replaced, that's all.